# Extracting links from a html-file with c++ regex

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to extract links from a wegpage using this regular expression:

```
std::regex e("<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>");
```

but sadly my programm exits with the `what<>: regex_error`.

Is there a way without using third party libraries or do I have to use something like *boost* here?

Update: 
I edit in my regex code, that is pretty much taken from the regex-example of [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/)

```
std::regex e("<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>");

std::smatch m;
std::cout << "The following links were found:" << std::endl;
std::string s = getCodeFromSite("cplusplus.com"); //provides me with the hmtl code as a string

while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto x:m) std::cout << x << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

Comment: We need more info to help you, make a test program to test it -- possibilities to get help will be much higher then.

Comment: try `std::regex re("<a\\s[^>]*href=(\"?)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");`

Comment: Also it seems, your regex is broken (-vvvvv error message).

Comment: @poxip I updated my post a little.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this doesn't work as well, same error.